# Javascript accessing functions of same class

Tags: javascript

In the following code:

```
function xyz(x) {
          //something
          this.x = x;
        }
        xyz.prototype = {
            a: function () {
                //do something
            },
            b: function () {
                //pre
                this.a();
                //post
            }
        }
```

the call of `this.a()` gives the warning of `method not supported`. So I tried using `xyz.prototype.a.call(this)` instead. But it does not maintain the value of x. What do I do to call one method of a class from other?

Comment: You did not show how function "b()" is called when you run into that error.

Comment: This obviously instead the actual code, right? Method not supported is return from the web server if it only has GET and you try to POST or anyother non-support/implemented verb

Comment: ^No that problem is sure not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code, if you write:

```
var myXyz = new xyz("hello");
```

then calling

```
myXyz.b();
```

should correctly get to the "a()" function on the prototype.  However, if you do something like this:

```
var otherB = myXyz.b;

otherB();
```

then it will **not** work, because there's no context object (that is, the `this` value inside "b()" won't be set correctly to an instance of "xyz").  That often happens when a function is being used as an event handler:

```
 something.onclick = myXyz.b;
```

The event handler, when called, won't have an "xyz" instance to work with.  Instead of that, therefore, you could write:

```
 something.onclick = function() { myXyz.b(); };
```

which clearly ensures that there's an "xyz" object.